# HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse callback on the same thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, callback, httpwebrequest

Is it possible that a call to a `Begin...` method (that takes a callback and an object and returns an `IAsyncResult`), specifically `HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse`, will call the callback on the same thread, thus if not handled correctly will cause a hang in case the callback releases a wait-handle?
If so, what is the best way to handle that case? Should I use the return value to make sure the request was already handled and release the wait-handle (or not wait on it in the first place)? Will the callback be called in such case?

I know it happens for sure with `HttpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream` (I learned it the hard way). But is it possible it'll happen with `HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse` also?

What I'm facing are rare hangs of the test suite and I narrowed it down to the communication library, where (unless I missed something) all relevant communication are being done asynchronously with `HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse` and `AutoResetEvent` for wait handles.

Comment: You can try ConfigureAwait(false) for async - await call pattern, like HttpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream().ConfigureAwait(false); ConfigureAwait(false) makes sure that when control returns after executing the asyncronous call, controll can pick any available thread and continue execution need to wait for the same thread which called the async method.

Comment: @ShankarS I think you are mixing the `async/await` pattern with the `Begin.../End...` pattern.

Comment: The APM (Asynchronous Programming Model) considered as deprecated and the suggested approach is the TAP. You can use the `FromAsync` ([1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/interop-with-other-asynchronous-patterns-and-types#from-apm-to-tap)) to convert APM to TAP.

Comment: I know, but looking at the code TAP generates makes me feel I don't fully understand what's going on, while the APM is very simple to understand.

Comment: With TAP you would not need to use wait handlers, because `await` those this signalling for you. That means the complexity is reduced when you use TAP (from the consumer perspective). I would suggest to give it a try and if you stuck somewhere then ask.

Comment: I already gave TAP a try. I don't like it. Seems to me everyone know exactly how to use it and showcases demos that work, but when it comes to real project, I only saw it work on javascript which took the idea from C# and to my opinion perfected it. The entire idea of await/async the whole flow (once you want some method to `await` something it must be marked `async` and if you want to use an `async` method in another method you must `await` so it's an endless loop) just doesn't feel right.